# Getting the public playlists of an other user with API v3 client library

Tags: youtube-api, playlist

I want to get the public playlists of an other user, so not of the logged in user. I checked the v3 Javascript client library and it seems to me it can only retrieve the playlist of the current authenticated user. Is it true? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will do it the same way you do the authorized user.

First you'll call [channels->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) with [id](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#id) or [forUsername](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#forUsername) and get [uploads playlist id](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads).

Then with [playlistItems->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) with the [playlistId](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#playlistId), you'll get the list items.

Also, here's [the javascript client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/).